# MSVC Bug? Overloaded member not found for constrained function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, c++20

This code fails to compile using MSVC 19.27.29112.0, but works with GCC 10.2.0. C++20 is enabled in both cases:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Blah {
    void blah() requires (sizeof(T) == 4);
};

template <typename T>
void Blah<T>::blah() requires (sizeof(T) == 4) {}

int main() {
    Blah<int> b;
    b.blah();

    return 0;
}
```

> error C2511: 'void Blah::blah(void)': overloaded member function not found in 'Blah'

The error only occurs if the `requires` depends on the class's template type. For example, `requires (sizeof(int) == 4)` works fine. Converting `blah()` to a templated function and doing something like `requires (sizeof(U) == 4)` also works.

Can anyone confirm this is a compiler bug?

Comment: [submitted as a compiler bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1232250/contrained-function-with-trailing-requires-within.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment*.)    This looks like a bug, indeed, and I suggest you formally [report it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html).

Curiously enough, the following works, instead.

```
template <typename T>
struct Blah {
    enum { sizeofT = sizeof(T) };  // or: static const size_t sizeofT = sizeof(T);
                                   // or: static constexpr size_t sizeofT = sizeof(T);
    void blah() requires (sizeofT == 4);
};

template <typename T>
void Blah<T>::blah() requires (sizeofT == 4) {}

int main() {
    Blah<int>().blah();       // ok
    Blah<float>().blah();     // ok

//  Blah<short>().blah()      // c7500: 'blah': no function satisfied its constraints
//  Blah<double>().blah();    // c7500: 'blah': no function satisfied its constraints

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, gcc and clang knows the existent overload in your code ([here](https://godbolt.org/z/of66d1)). However, I think the MS compiler team would have pipelined the memory initialization module at a different stage as compared to gcc and clang. I (kind-of) speculate this since the following code works (i.e., initialize and create memory for the blah() function in the struct template itself):

```
template<typename T>
struct Blah {
    void blah() requires (sizeof(T) == 4) {};
};

int main() {
    Blah<int> b;
    b.blah();
}
```